# How to set default search as file search for Vim plugin CtrlP?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ctrlp

I'm using [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) plugin for my vim for fuzzy file search.
I generally work on a large Symfony project & searching is very inefficient & slow but I figured that if I press `<c-d>` after `<c-p>` it searches by file name than file path which is way faster & what I want.

I'm not able to figure out how to set it as a default search mode when i hit `<c-p>` & it's not in their do either.

Can someone help me in this ?

Comment: Did you even read the plugin's documentation?

Comment: @romainl Thanks for pushing. I actually did read it but didn't used my head enough to figure out myself. Here's the solution: let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlP<c-d>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `let g:ctrlp_by_filename=1` to your vimrc

Full documentation [Here](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt)